# wp_dropdown_categories how to get array?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to customizing my wordpress theme.  This code returns a select box:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
```

A dropdown select box is returned, which looks like this:

```
<select name="scat" id="scat" class="searchbar" tabindex="2">
    <option value="0">All Categories</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="19">Other</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="11">Police Support</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="25">Pub Security</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="23">Restaurant Security</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="16">Retail &amp; Audit</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="21">Retail Security</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="14">Security Management</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="8">Security Systems</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="42">Self Employed</option>
</select>
```

I don't want the select box to be returned, i just want the option values in an array.  How do i get the option values?

Comment: I think you're asking this question: "How do I get an array with the list of catagories?" Am I right?

Comment: ?  This is the code for the theme i purchased, it returns a select box.  I want to customize the theme, how do i return the option values no the select box?

Comment: The values being returned in this example are the Wordpress site's "categories". You can generally customize the site's categories in the admin area.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of categories with

```
<?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?>
```

For reference, read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)